# Reverse proxy using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web-scraping, reverse-proxy

I am trying to create a reverse-proxy web application using flask. I don't really know it is called reverse-proxy exactly but my webapp gets url from `../proxy/<url>` and using `requests` and `bs4` in python scrape the website and do some change in `<a href="</test>">` to `<a href="../proxy/<domain>/test">` and same for `<form>` and for other links also in the website for making sure that next request to the page is through proxy but some page that uses JavaScript to load data doesn't goes through `../proxy`, they just send request like a normal website.

Now here is my question,

Is there any way to create an environment  like things to make every link go through proxy or what could be the other best way to do such reverse-proxy things in flask? How to make sure that each and every time that website connect to network then connect through the proxy?

Edit: Idea:

1. Making browser log like things using JavaScript, but while any link want to connect to internet then manipulate it into `/proxy/<url>`.
2. CORS: I don't know what to say but make CORS or using CORS to block request to other domain.

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: If you were only targeting a few specific sites rather than all sites on the Internet, you have to analyze the JavaScript code executed on these sites to see what happened. Either yourself or your code have to work like a real browser JS engine, and simple find-and-replace won't work in most cases.

Comment: You mean it is possible, but its very hard to do, or can't do. Can we make JS engine in my circumstances?

Comment: Now I understand what JS engine is, I don't think we can do this kind of thing. So, Should I have to leave this question here or I can wait for other answers?

Comment: If the target site does not involve much ajax interactions with the backend server, you may run the JS code in a headless Chrome on the proxy server and return the Javascript generated DOM. This technique is called server-side rendering, and there are frameworks such as selenium and pyppeteer to help developers control the headless browser.

Comment: There is ajax, this reverse-proxy is for all of the sites in internet. And doesn't website contain ajax? That's obvious answer. I am asking that is there a way to know that it is going to make a request to the internet using javascript and manipulate that into `/proxy/..` , this things is like network log or something like that where we can know before it make request to internet and able to manipulate it.

Comment: I see what you are doing here. `Javascript` will be the largest headache but not all of them. Non-static content that needs to access heterogeneous resources will mostly use a GET and/or POST to a lesser extent to do it. Since you are filtering your traffic through Flask, you can always intervene with those HTTP commands, especially those directed to resources ending with `.js`. You can either redirect it to alternative caches that you have cooked, point them at copies at your local resources, or even request it in proxy for them.

Comment: @BilalQandeel I didn't completely understand, what you are talking about, can you please explain a little briefly with some examples? I am actually new in these kindof things but have experience in `flask` and `javascript`. Are you taking about filtering `js` code while sending as response or ...? And as I already said I didn't understand completely but not all website loads javascript with `.js` extension only some even doesn't have `.js` extension in their url/path. I had found that also! What is `HTTP command`?

Comment: Take a look at this [HTTP methods using Flask](https://pythonbasics.org/flask-http-methods/) and this: [Flask redirects](https://www.askpython.com/python-modules/flask/flask-redirect-url)

Comment: I know, how to use both of them. But do you really think, this is going to solve my issue because I don't think it is making any sense here. Can you please explain how this is going to help me?

Comment: Here is something that I have stumbled upon describing [proxies and reverse proxies](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ozhe__GdWC8]

Comment: I don't find this video, useful. I am looking for completely different things but you are giving the link of how it works! I know how it worked, but I wanna know how to change the content or make environment for browser so that each and every request made by that site will go through `/proxy/<URL>` . Anyway thanks for great video, but remove this comment cuz I found this video here for only promotion.